# Rendering more than one .vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Right now my Vue is rendering the component `dnaMoleculeFileInfo`. How can I add another component to be rendered with its own props?

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(dnaMoleculeFileInfo, {
        props: {
            format: data.dnamoleculefile.format,
            id: data.dnamoleculefile.id,
            name: data.dnamoleculefile.name,
            sequence: data.sequence.bases,
            sequenceLength: data.length
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: If you want two components, you will have to render a container and the two components as children.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this.

```js
console.clear()

const dnaMoleculeFileInfo = {
  template:`<h2>I'm a dnaMoleculeFileInfo</h2>`
}

const someOtherComponent = {
  template:`<h2>I'm some other component</h2>`
}

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render(h){
      // Add the props you want to these two components
      const dna = h(dnaMoleculeFileInfo)
      const other = h(someOtherComponent)
      // return a container with both of them as children
      return h("div", [dna, other])
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```